# How to add whitespace around an icon in matteborder

Tags: java, swing

I experimented with `MatteBorder` in order to display an icon at the start of a `JTextField` (similiar to search icons being displayed in a textfield).

This is my current implementation:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Filter", 8);
textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, 24));
Border outer = textField.getBorder();
// ugly workaround
Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2);
Border search = new MatteBorder(0, 16, 0, 0, icon);
textField.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new CompoundBorder(outer, padding), search));
```

The icon is a 16x16px icon with no whitespace around it. The textfield is 24px high. I introduced a padding Border to have some whitespace around the icon (otherwise it would display a full icon and the first 4px of the icon under it). My problem is that there is no whitespace to the right of the icon (where the user enters text).

**Question:** Is there a way to have a defined amount of whitespace around the image, so it does not tile? Can I somehow add "padding" around the icon before I add it to the `MatteBorder`?

P.S. I know that I could add whitespace around the image file, but it is used in other instances where there should not be any whitespace around it.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a MatteBorder always tiles the icon, I would not use it.  I would just write a custom border:

```
static void updateBorder(JTextField textField,
                         Icon icon) {

    Border iconBorder = new AbstractBorder() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c,
                                      Insets insets)
        {
            insets.left = icon.getIconWidth() + 4;
            insets.right = insets.top = insets.bottom = 0;
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c,
                                Graphics g,
                                int x,
                                int y,
                                int width,
                                int height)
        {
            icon.paintIcon(c, g,
                x, y + (height - icon.getIconHeight()) / 2);
        }
    };

    Border oldBorder = textField.getBorder();

    // Inside text field's original border, place icon border
    // with a little empty space around it.
    textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        oldBorder,
        BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2),
            iconBorder)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that there is no whitespace to the right of the icon (where the user enters text).

How about using a second `CompoundBorder` to add extra space on the inside of the Border?

Another possiblility is to use the [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) which allows you to add a component to a Border. So you could add a JLabel with an Icon.